# Proof that if $R_{1};R_{2}=R_{2};R_{1}$ is a relation on a set $S$, then $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ are bijective maps

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-set-theory, proof-writing

For the surjectivity part, I believe I have managed to prove the claim. And for Injectivity, I've tried to show that if $aR_{1};R_{2}c$ and $bR_{2};R_{1}c$, then $a=b$ but I am not entirely sure what $a=b$ means in this context. Do I have to show that there is an equivalence relation containing (a,b)?

Comment: What do your assumptions men? (the part after "if" in the title)

Comment: It denotes a composition of two relations $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$

Comment: So each semicolon ; means composition? [Usual notation for that is a circle like $R_1 \circ R_2$]

Comment: Yes, I believe they want me to prove that if $f \circ g=g \circ f $ then $f$ and $g$ are bijective but from a more general point of view namely the functions as relations.

Comment: Sei-- why did you already ask this (see reference to "exact duplicate) and then post the question again?

Answer (score 0):

Something is missing in the question. Take $S=\{a,b\}$ and take $R_1$ and $R_2$ to be the relations defined by the function $f:x\mapsto a$.
Then, $R_1;R_2=f\circ f=R_2;R_1$, but $f$ is not injective nor surjective.

Comment: I believe it makes no difference but the exact wording of the question was "Suppose $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ are relations on a set S with $R_{1};R_{2} = I $ and $R_{2};R_{1} = I$.
Prove that both $R_{1}$ and $R_{2}$ are bijective maps"

Comment: Well, it makes all the difference, on the contrary.

Comment: Hint: first prove injectivity of $R_1$: if $xR_1z$ and $yR_1z$, let $w$ be such that $zR_2w$. Then $xR_1;R_2w$ and $yR_1;R_2w$, but $R_1:R_2=1$, so $x=w=y$. Similarly, $R_2$ is injective. Now, prove that $R_1$ and $R_2$ are actually applications and finally that they are surjective.

Comment: what do you mean by $R_{1}: R_{2}=1$? Is $:$ different from $;$? and how is it equal to 1?

Comment: This is a typo. : is ; and 1 is $I$.

Comment: I still don't see how that implies $x=w=y$